# App for aligning with old picture while taking new picture (Samsung Galaxy S7)

Tags: android, apps

I am looking for an app that lets me see an overlay of an old picture while taking a new picture. The old picture should however not be visible in the new picture when it is saved. This should also work with the front camera of the Samsung Galaxy S7.

Is there such an app, preferably for free? I could not yet find one.

Comment: This is essentially a *shopping question*, even though you don't want to pay for what you want. [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80255/is-there-a-way-use-live-view-tethered-and-superimpose-a-transparent-view-of-the

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is called **onion skinning**. Available apps are constantly changing. You can [search Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=onion%20skin%20camera&c=apps) to find a suitable app.